# Does $\pi$ contain every real?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

One can generate decimal expansions between $0$ and $1$ by taking with the $m$th digit of $\pi$, and then taking every $n$th digit.

$\pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399...$

for instance, for $m=3$, $n=5$, this will be

3.1**4**1592**6**5358**9**7932**3**8462**6**4338**3**2795**0**2884**1**9716**9**399...

giving

$0.469363019...$

I can't see why this shouldn't be able to create every real number. But if this creates any real number given a pair if natural numbers $m$ and $n$, it would mean that the cardinality of the continuum is equal to that of the natural numbers.

So I guess this method can't create any real. But why?

Comment: You literally answered your own question. Also, it's unknown whether the decimal expansion of $\pi$ becomes only 1's and 0's after a certain point, so you definitely can't prove as of now that every real number occurs as a subsequence of the digits of $\pi$, let alone in the manner you described.

Comment: The number of pairs $n, \: k$ is countable!

Comment: I think the more interesting question is : give an example of a real number that cannot be produced like this.

Comment: My guess is that this process never creates a rational, as that would require infinite repetition. I don't know if this can be proven using the current tools though.

Comment: @SmileyCraft I think it is possible to prove that infinite number of rational numbers cannot be created(although I didn't done it), but proving that no rational is there sounds hard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically present a mapping from $\mathbb N^2$ to $\mathbb R$ and ask if the mapping is surjective. Since $\mathbb N^2$ is countable, and $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, a simple diagonalization argument can be made to show that the mapping *cannot* be surjective.

In particular, the argument would go like so:

1. Let $F$ be the mapping you construct going from $\mathbb N^2$ to $[0,1]$. That is, $F(m,n)$ is the number obtained by taking with the $m$th digit of $\pi$, and then taking every $n$th digit.
2. Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N^2$ be a bijective function. (*we know such a function exists, and it doesn't really matter which one we take*) and let $f_1,f_2$ be its components, i.e. $f(n)=(f_1(n), f_2(n))$.
3. Denote the digits of $F(f(n))$ as $a_i^{(n)}$, that is, $F(f(n)) = 0.a_1^{(n)}a_2^{(n)}a_3^{(n)}\dots$
4. Let $$b_i=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if } a_i^{(i)} = 0\\ 0& \text{if } a_i^{(i)} \neq 0\end{cases}$$
5. Let $b=0.b_1b_2b_3\dots$. Clearly, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, we see that $F(f(n))\neq b$ because the $n$-th digit of $F(f(n))$ is not the same as the $n$-th digit of $b$.
6. From $5$, it follows that the number $b$ is not in the domain of $F\circ f$.
7. Because $f$ is bijective, we conclude that $b$ is not in the domain of $F$.

Comment: Thank you for the clean re-wording. The diagonalization argument will fail when you can show that the number is just further down the list, as in this case

Comment: @MrMartin The diagonalization argument can show that any mapping from a countable set to $\mathbb R$ cannot be surjective. It will not fail. It is possible to construct a number that is not in your mapping.

Comment: @MrMartin: how can you draw any conclusion about a diagonalization argument without even seeing it ? Or you need to prove that no such argument can be written.

Comment: Following this line of reasoning, the diagonalization argument could also be applied to show that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is greater than itself.

Comment: @MrMartin I updated my answer to show you how you can prove that your mapping is not surjective. If you think you can use the diagonalization argument could also be applied to show that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is greater than itself, I advise you to demonstrate this claim by actually showing that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is greater than itself.

Comment: @5xum You're right, it can't, precisely because $\mathbb R$ is not countable. Thank you for the clarifications

Comment: @MrMartin Happy to help. Remember to accept the answer if it is what you needed. And a piece of general advice: avoid giving sweeping statements like "the diagonalization argument could also be applied to show that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is greater than itself. " before trying to prove them. It makes you sound like you get an answer and immediatelly assume it is wrong. The aggressive tone may not go down well with everyone.